# Solving formula for confidence intervals on two proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion

I'm interested in comparing two independent proportions from two samples. The formula for doing so is available in the Internet (e.g. [here](http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06d2pop.html)). So far, so good.

But my main purpose is not to build a confidence interval. Rather I want to assess how big the second proportion has to be to be significant higher than the first proportion (given an alpha level and both sample sizes).

Suppose I conducted a study and found that 80% of 154 respondents used product X. Suppose further that I will do a second study with the same questions and I'm going for n=200 respondents. How big has this second proportion to be, to be signifcantly higher on a 90% alpha level?

Could anyone provide me with the specific formula which is solved for the second proportion? I know there are online calculators or GPower for exactly such purposes, but unfortunately I have to build up theses formula in Excel and thus have to put them in on my own.

(I originally [posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918883/solving-formula-for-confidence-intervals-on-two-proportions), but was told that for statistics I might be better with posting my question here again, so sorry for crossposting!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you did want to create a confidence interval for the difference of two proportions, there are better procedures than the one you are using: you might consider making use of the Wilson procedure. The [Wikipedia article on binomial confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) mentions this and several other possibilities, but does not show the method applied to *differences* in proportions: for that, consult a reference such as  Newcombe, Robert G., "Interval Estimation for the Difference Between Independent Proportions: Comparison of Eleven Methods," *Statistics in Medicine*, **17**, 873-890 (1998).

However it appears that you don't want to create a confidence interval, but rather perform a hypothesis test. The formula you would want to use is a rearranged version of the given one. Let me write $p_a$ and $p_b$ for the proportions in groups A and B, and their sample sizes as $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then your test statistic is:

$$z = \frac{p_a - p_b}{\sqrt{\frac{p_a(1-p_a)}{m}+\frac{p_b(1-p_b)}{n}}}$$

Your result will be significant if this exceeds the upper critical value $z_\text{crit} = \Phi^{-1}(1 - \alpha/2)$ (where $\alpha$ is your significance level) or if it is below the lower critical value, which by symmetry of the normal distribution is $-z_\text{crit}$.  If you were interested in a 90% confidence interval, note that this is equivalent to setting $\alpha$ as 10%, not as 90%! These two sides of significance correspond to whether the proportions differ because $p_a$ exceeds $p_b$ (positive $z$) or vice versa (negative $z$). If you are interested in the critical values for $p_a$ which make this just significant, then you need to solve this equation as equal to $\pm z_\text{crit}$. Although your question mentions only the uppper critical value I will write as if you are interested in both possibilities - partly because this corresponds better to what you mentioned about the upper and lower bounds of a 90% confidence interval, and partly because two-sided testing is usually a good idea in general. The upper limit you get by testing with $\alpha$ as 10% is equivalent to the one-sided test you'd get if you tested at 5%, so no great variation in the method is required.

If you feel daunted by the task of algebraic rearrangement, one option is to use a [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) to do the work for you. One freely available, open source product is [Sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_%28mathematics_software%29) (which is actually rather more powerful than just a CAS). Rearranging to make one variable the subject, is essentially the same as solving the equation for that variable *in terms of the other variables*. A brief [tutorial on how to solve equations symbolically in Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_algebra.html) is here. This would then give you a formula you can set up in Excel.

A paid-for product is Mathematica, but many basic features of Mathematica are freely available online at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). Go there and type:

```
solve z=(a-b)/sqrt((a(1-a))/m + (b(1-b))/n) for a
```

The output will be:

[image: Rearranged formula for binomial difference of proportions test]

Here I have written $z_\text{crit}$ as $z$, $p_a$ as $a$ and $p_b$ as $b$ but I hope the meaning is still clear. Simply by changing $m$, $n$, $z$ and $b$ into appropriate cell references you can easily implement this formula in Excel. If cell `A1` contains your level of signficance, $\alpha$, then then the cell you use for the critical $z$-score should contain the formula `=NORM.S.INV(1-A1/2)` so you should get the famous `1.96` (to two decimal places) if you set $\alpha$ at the 5% level, or `1.64` if you test at 10%.

Note that we actually find two solutions arise, corresponding to the two critical values for $a$, without having to check `solve -z=(a-b)/sqrt((a(1-a))/m + (b(1-b))/n) for a` for the case with negative $z$. It is clear that the first line of the rearrangement is must be:

$$z_\text{crit}^2 = \frac{(p_a - p_b)^2}{\frac{p_a(1-p_a)}{m}+\frac{p_b(1-p_b)}{n}}$$

Beyond this point it no longer matters whether we used the positive or negative value for $z_\text{crit}$. It's not so hard to see where Mathematica derives it solution from. Multiply by the denominator and we obtain:

$$z_\text{crit}^2 \left(\frac{p_a(1-p_a)}{m}+\frac{p_b(1-p_b)}{n}\right)= (p_a - p_b)^2$$

Then multiply by $mn$:

$$z_\text{crit}^2 \left(np_a(1-p_a) + mp_b(1-p_b)\right)= mn(p_a - p_b)^2$$

Once the brackets are multiplied out and terms are collected together, this will be a quadratic in $p_a$. The form of Mathematica's solutions were just the two roots to the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) but it's easier to let it deal with the simplification!

Comment: Hi Silverfish. Many thanks for your helpful, detailed and understandable answer. I think for now there are no questions left. Thx!

Comment: @deschen It's a good idea to make sure you are very clear, particularly for when it comes to reporting your results, about the significance level and confidence level - they're not the same thing! I have clarified a little about one- and two-tailed testing. Again, when writing up results, it's important to state whether you used a one- or two-sided test.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm indeed conducting a one-sided test, but am aware of the statistical implications (changing alpha-level, looking for critical z-valuse and so on). But thanks anyway.

Comment: @deschen No problem - in that case you can dispense with the division by two in the `1-alpha/2` when you're calculating the critical $z$, and you'll only need the proportion formula taking the positive square root.